# how to insert data in the tooltip of a highcharts chart?

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts

i  have a json file of this type:

```
[["SSL Certificate Signed Using Weak Hashing Algorithm",4500,"98","10980"],["SSL Self-Signed Certificate",2000,"98","-1"],...]
```

and the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
var options = {     
chart: {renderTo:'grafico1',type:'column'},     
series: [{    }]    
};   

$.getJSON('json.json', function(data){    
options.series[0].data = data;     
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
 });
});
```

in the graph that is generated, the columns perfectly indicate the numerical value of the arrays. In addition to the numeric value, the first element of the array is correctly displayed in the tooltip. I would like the third and fourth element of the array to appear in the tooltip, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the keys feature to anchor these values into the point object,
2. Use the `tooltip.formatter` callback to set the format of the displayed tooltip,

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jrhdg7ue/

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter() {
      let output = `<span style="font-size: 10px">${this.key}</span><br/>` + `<span style="color:${this.color}">●</span> ${this.series.name}: <b>${this.y}</b><br/> value: ${this.point.value} <br/> value1: ${this.point.value1}`

      return output
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys